# Make a variation in Sibelius

Tags: sibelius, sonata

I'm writing a sonata for piano. And I'm writing it in the Sibelius app.
I've finished the first movement. I want to write the next movement after the first movement in that project. But I don't know how.
I mean I wanna write a new score in a project with new starting.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to write two consecutive movements in the same file?

Comment: @Dekkadeci yes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start a new movement, or new piece in a collection of pieces, you'll need to do a few things:

- make sure you have a **page break** at the end of the previous movement (or at least a **line break**). To do a page break, select the last barline of the previous movement and press **Cmd-A** (on a Mac, let me know if you need PC shortcuts).
- create a **bar number change**, set to number "1" and put it at the beginning of the new movement.
- put a **final barline** at the end of the previous movement.
- when putting the new key-signature and time-signature at the beginning of the new movement, go to **more options** and deselect **allow cautionary**. This stops the change of key and time-signature appearing at the end of the previous movement.
- you could also choose to have the full instrument name at the beginning of the new movement. This is quite useful in a score with several instruments; it is probably not necessary for a solo piano sonata. The easiest way to do this is to select the last barline of the previous section, open the **inspector** and select **Section end**.
- you will need to add a new title, and will also need to drag the first stave of the new movement down a bit, to make room for the title.

This answer tells you what you need to do. Let me know if you also need all the shortcuts or menus to do all these things. As far as I know there isn't a way to do all this with one operation.

Comment: Yes please. May you say the Windows shortcuts?